Unity Direct3D and SharpDX helper APIs
I've been working on a UWP streaming app using sharpdx and I've gotten it working as a standalone visual studio project. However it requires the use of Microsoft's Direct3D helper APIs.
This does not cause any issues in visual studio, however when I transfer my code over to Unity it is unable to import d3d11.dll required in the helpers. I do not want to include a d3d11.dll file in my Unity project. Is there a way I could still use this dll in unity? Perhaps just using the header files if they are available? All I need is the functionality of these helper methods.

What do you mean exactly by "unable to import d3d11.dll"? If the program is running of Windows (of course), d3d11 should be there in %windir%\system32

@SimonMourier I'm running the program on the Hololens 2, (uwp arm64) and i'm unsure how system dlls work there. It does work as you say on desktop however. But on hololens the error I get is: Unable to load DLL 'd3d11.dll'. Tried the load the following dynamic libraries: Unable to load dynamic library 'd3d11.dll' because of 'Failed to open the requested dynamic library (0x06000000) - The specified module could not be found.  (WinError:0000007e)

Sounds like there's no Direct3D on this machine but I can't really say. Can you run dxdiag.exe on it?

@SimonMourier there is direct3d on the device, as long as I use wrapper code to interact with directx everything works fine. The root issue I'm having is converting sharpdx texture2d into a direct3d surface which I can't find a wrapper for.
